# Reading a list of credit card numbers from XML

Tags: java, xml, validation, xml-serialization, javabeans

- I have a program that validates credit card numbers using the Luhn Algorithm and throws user-defined exceptions.
- I have cc_expired_db.xml containg a list of Expired credit card numbers.
- I have cc_stolen_db.xml containing a list of Stolen credit card numbers.

Please view the [pseudo code](http://pastebin.com/Lyd7MasT) of my intended output.

Upon individual testing, I have managed to get the Luhn Algorithm to work and it throws the invalid exception upon FAILED.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean checkCreditCard(String strCardNumber, double amount, String luhnStatus)
    throws ExpiredCreditCardException, InvalidCreditCardException,
    StolenCreditCardException {

    if(luhnStatus.equals("PASSED")) {
        if() { // missing condition for expired
            throw new ExpiredCreditCardException();

        } else if() { // missing condition for stolen
            throw new StolenCreditCardException();
        }

    } else if(luhnStatus.equals("FAILED")) { // invalid
        throw new InvalidCreditCardException();

    } else {
        payItem(amount);
        System.out.print("Thank you for shopping with us!");
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have successfully [written](http://pastebin.com/2YMmCWSU) and [read](http://pastebin.com/ZhXrunaJ) XML using a tutorial.

However, I am not sure how to put the conditions for expired and stolen exceptions in the if-statements as intended in my pseudo-code.

Comment: You can change the date to long and use - and compare if You need Date Util in java i can send you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both `if` statements, define a method for each that resembles `isExpired(String strCardNumber)` or `isStolen(String strCardNumber)`, which return booleans. These methods can iterate through the entries in their respective files, and if a match is found, return true. Your code then becomes:

```
if (isExpired(strCardNumber)) {
    throw new ExpiredCreditCardException();
} else if (isStolen(strCardNumber)) {
    throw new StolenCreditCardException();
}
```

I'd also recommend, if there are no other values for the value `luhnStatus` using a boolean value which could be more appropriately be called `isValidNumber` or something to that effect. If there aren't more than the two values `PASSED` and `FAILED`, the the `payItem` block will never be reached. To fix this, you could put the `payItem` block after the two `if` statements, as it will be skipped if an exception occurs.

Sample pseudo-code `ifExpired` method:

```
private boolean isExpired(String strCardNumber) {
    for each card number in expired card numbers:
        if strCardNumber.equals(current number of iteration):
            return true;

     after iteration, return false as the value was not contained.
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion. I will also take into account your tip about `luhnStatus` just being boolean. Would you kindly provide a template code for the `isExpired(String strCardNumber)` with the answer? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, my apologies but this might be a weakness for me. I'm very new to the XML. Might you provide an actual code for this? [Here](https://app.box.com/s/wj8u6d7kwzxuurwdodpp) are the source code I used and the actual XML if it will be of any help. Sorry, again. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I have implemented your recommendation with `luhnStatus` and it is indeed more elegant ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iPR3DSwS)). I temporarily hardcoded the numbers in the XML so I can run the program. Thanks again. I'm now only missing the boolean methods. If you would so kindly assist with the method, it would be a great reference for me in learning how to deal with XML. Your assistance is well noted.

Comment: Hi, I am accepting this as answer, since you did answer the main question of "what to put in the conditions". I might ask the method in a separate question. Thanks again.

Comment: I got the method! I used XMLDecoder and used foreach. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

While reading the XML files, you have to store the entries for each type of credit card (stolen or expired) inside a List.

The following is part-pseudocode, part-java:

```
List<String> expiredCCList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (reading_CC_Expired.xml) {
    String expiredCC = readEntryFromExpiredXML();
    expiredCCList.add(expiredCC);
}


List<String> stolenCCList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (reading_CC_Stolen.xml) {
    String stolenCC = readEntryFromStolenXML();
    stolenCCList.add(stolenCC);
}
```

After populating these lists, you can call your code like this:

```
public boolean checkCreditCard(String strCardNumber, double amount, String luhnStatus)  ExpiredCreditCardException, InvalidCreditCardException,  {

if(luhnStatus.equals("PASSED")) {
    if(expiredCCList.contains(strCardNumber)) {
        throw new ExpiredCreditCardException();

    } else if(stolenCCList.contains(strCardNumber) {
        throw new StolenCreditCardException();
    }

} else if(luhnStatus.equals("FAILED")) { // invalid
    throw new InvalidCreditCardException();

} else {
    payItem(amount);
    System.out.print("Thank you for shopping with us!");
}

return true;
}
```

I left a code snippet for you on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrielruiu/10261502)